# No string output for char conversion

Tags: sql-server

I have a Char(1) Nullable column (District) that I want to output "Not assigned" when NULL;

I've tried

```
SELECT CASE District
        WHEN NULL
            THEN 'Not Assigned'
        ELSE District
        END AS District
    ,[Name]
    ,AgencyType
FROM cli_Agency
```

and

```
SELECT CASE CONVERT(VARCHAR, District)
        WHEN NULL
            THEN 'Not Assigned'
        ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, District)
        END AS District
    ,[Name]
    ,AgencyType
FROM cli_Agency
```

But Null is displayed instead of 'Not Assigned'.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a syntax issue

```
...
CASE WHEN District IS NULL THEN 'Not Assigned' ELSE District END AS District,
...
```

You could also write it as

```
IsNull(District,'Not Assigned') as District,
```

Or Even

```
coalesce(District,'Not Assigned') as District,
```

Comment: @user3140169 Always happy to help.   Learning is the fun part :)

Comment: i still had to convert it to a varchar. Otherwise the result was 'N'. 
IsNull(CAST(District AS varchar(12)),'Not Assigned') as District

Comment: @user3140169 Ah .. I see you char(1) now!   You should really specify the length  for example varchar(25)  .